# How to animate fragment animation in conditional navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-architecture-navigation

To animate the animation between destinations in the navigation component, one can specify the following attributes in the action tag like below.

```
<fragment
    .........>
    <action
        ........
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
```

I read about conditional navigation (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional), it suggested that some screens, for example, a login screen should be handled independently from navigation flow.

[image]

```
<navigation
        .........
        app:startDestination="@id/main_fragment">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.MainFragment"
            android:label="fragment_main"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/navigate_to_profile_fragment"
                app:destination="@id/profile_fragment"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.LoginFragment"
            android:label="login_fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment"/>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.ProfileFragment"
            android:label="fragment_profile"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"/>
</navigation>
```

I want to redirect from ProfileFragment to LoginFragment when the user hasn't authenticated yet with animations. I understand that we can define the transitions explicitly on the LoginFragment when enter or exit the fragment.

```
 class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          val inflater = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext())
          enterTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right)
          exitTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.fade)
     }
  }

class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
      .......
      navController.navigate(R.id.login_fragment)
      .......
}
```

I wonder if there are other ways around to animate from ProfileFragment to LoginFragment with animation using the navigation component or anim attributes like we have on the action tag without specifying it in LoginFragment.

Comment: If you want to use Transitions, you have to use the Fragment APIs. What is your issue with using those APIs?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I want to animate the animations not necessarily transitions when navigating from ProfileFragment to LoginFragment since on the <fragment> tag there are no anim attributes like the <action> tag.

Comment: I don't think I follow. If you are using Transitions, you absolutely shouldn't be using animations therefore you don't need, want, or should be using the `enterAnim`, etc. at all. If you use both, they will conflict with one another (and Transitions are much, much better of a system if you had to choose between them).

Comment: Let me put Transitions aside. I want to redirect from ProfileFragment to LoginFragment when user is not authenticated. Since login_fragment is not an action inside the profile_fragment, I can't define the enterAnim, etc. How can I show the animations when navigating these two fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an action that needs to be accessible to multiple destinations (as you might want your `navigate_to_profile_fragment` action to be), this is precisely the use case for [global actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) - actions defined at the `<navigation>` graph level, rather than associated with just a single destination. This means that any destination in your graph can trigger the action via `navigate(R.id.navigate_to_profile_fragment)`

```
<navigation
    .........
    app:startDestination="@id/main_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_profile_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/profile_fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.LoginFragment"
        android:label="login_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.conditionalnav.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"/>
</navigation>
```